# Was there ever a non-1st Edition version of the Machamp found in the 2-player Starter Set?

Tags: pokemon

Back when I collected Pokémon cards, I received a [2-Player Starter Set](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/2-Player_Starter_Set_(TCG)), which included a 1st Edition Holographic Machamp. As far as I know, everybody who got this set received the same 1st Edition Machamp card.

Was there ever a non-1st Edition version of the starter set Machamp released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Machamp_(Base_Set_8)):

> *A 1st Edition version of this card was included in the 2-Player Starter Set. While an Unlimited Edition version of the Base Set print of this card was never officially released, a Non Holofoil version of this card lacking the 1st Edition stamp was included in the Trainer Deck A, distributed to prototype Pokémon Leagues before the TCG officially launched in North America.*

So it look like all Foil Machamps from the Base set are 1st Editions ("Unlimited" refers to cards that are not 1st Edition).